# Dropzone additional data to pass into database

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

it's my first time to use dropzone.js and it works really great. Now, I am blocked by having an extra textarea to be filled by user but what happened is that the textarea value is not inserted into database only inserts the image uploaded. Actually the extra notes is working fine if i'll put it inside the form with class dropzone but I wanted it to be out of the form due to UI issue. Heres a lil bit code below:

HTML:

```
<form id="droper" action="" method="post" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="rotator_form">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="rotatorId" value="{{ $currentId }}">
                    <div class="fallback">
                        <input id="file" multiple name="file" type="file"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <textarea name="note" class="form-control" placeholder="Add notes here.."></textarea>

<button id="submit-droper" class="btn green" data-dismiss="modal">Submit Droper</button>
```

Script:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

  var rotatorDroper = new Dropzone('#droper', {
      url: "/rotator/image-upload",
      autoProcessQueue: false,
      beforeSend: function(file, xhr, formData){
      formData.append('notes', 'hehehe');
    }
  });

   $('#submit-droper').click(function(e){
       rotatorDroper.processQueue();
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send additional data while uploading files you can use `sending` event in the init dropzone param like this :

```
Dropzone.options.your_form_id = {

    init: function (e) {

        var myDropzone = this;

        // Event to send your custom data to your server
        myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, data) {

            // First param is the variable name used server side
            // Second param is the value, you can add what you what
            // Here I added an input value
            data.append("your_variable", $('#your_input').val());
        });

    }
};
```

As you can see `data.append` will help you to send key / value to your server easily through Ajax.

Don't forget to add an ID to your textarea to get it easily.